# Subset df using pandas filter and datetime functions

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to filter the following df:

```
datetemp | gamenum |score
2019-6-2    123      2
2019-4-5    314      4
2019-5-11   344      2
2019-4-29   324      1
2019-2-28   325      9
2019-1-30   231      7
```

I'm trying to do the following and it seems like it should work:

```
import datetime

dateone = datetime.date(2019, 4, 1)
datetwo = datetime.date(2019, 6, 12)


df_filted_by_date = df[[(df['DATE_temp'] >= dateone and df['DATE_temp'] <= datetwo )]]
df_filted_by_date
```

which should return:

```
datetemp | gamenum |score
2019-6-2    123      2
2019-4-5    314      4
2019-5-11   344      2
2019-4-29   324      1
```

However I am getting multiple errors depending on minor tweaks I make to the code above. It feels like the above *should* work. Any tips on how to solve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change a few things.

1) Change the way I made the date values:

```
import datetime

dateone = datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1)
datetwo = datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 12)
```

2) I added a new step to covert to pandas datetime:

```
df["datecol"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datecol"])
```

3) pandas filter using `loc`:

```
df_filted_by_date = df.loc[(df.datecol>= dateone) & (df.datecol<= datetwo)]
```

The full code looks like this:

```
import datetime

dateone = datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1)
datetwo = datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 12)

df["datecol"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datecol"])

df_filted_by_date = df.loc[(df.datecol>= dateone) & (df.datecol<= datetwo)]
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT -**

Converting to datetime format

```
df["DATE_temp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE_temp"])
```

Please use -

```
df_filted_by_date = df.loc[(df.DATE_temp>= dateone) & (df.DATE_temp<= datetwo)]
```

instead of

```
df_filted_by_date = df[[(df['DATE_temp'] >= dateone and df['DATE_temp'] <= datetwo )]]
```

You were only missing the order by which pandas uses operators. Need to pass the two comparisons in parenthesis and then apply AND (&).

Comment: I get this as en output error `TypeError: <class 'datetime.date'> type object 2019-04-01`

Comment: if i run `type(df.DATE_temp)` I get the following output: `pandas.core.series.Series`

Comment: Oh, so it is not in datetime format so you need to convert it to format by - `df["DATE_temp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE_temp"])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use DatetimeIndex slicing:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index) # need to convert into DatetimeIndex
df_filted_by_date = df['2019-04-01':'2019-06-12']
```

Comment: how do i make sure my `datecol` is in my index? or does `to_datetime` automatically index off of `datetime` objects

Comment: @JohnFriel You can set `datecol` to index column with `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['datecol'])`.

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for though. I want to be able to pass the datetime objects into a pandas filter. With your solution I would need to edit the dates manually each time.